# ReadConsoleInput read only first symbol after press Enter

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Excuse me for my English, but I can't solve a problem. Now I am writing Remote Console. It uses QTcpSocket and functions for work with windows console. Almost work perfect, but when I try read from console I need first press Enter and only after this my first letter will read. If I want input second letter I need press Enter again. How can I read every letters that I write?
It's my constructor:

```
FreeConsole();

    dwProcessId = 0 ;
    dwErrorId = 0;
    std::wstring path = L"cmd.exe";

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security = {
       sizeof(security), NULL, TRUE
     };

    if(CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR)path.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        dwProcessId = pi.dwProcessId;
    }
    else
    {
        dwErrorId = GetLastError();
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", dwErrorId);
        return;
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    if(!AttachConsole(pi.dwProcessId))
    {
        dwErrorId = GetLastError();
        printf( "AttachConsole failed (%d).\n", dwErrorId);
        return;
    }
```

and here function where i have a problem:

```
int Console::readInputFromConsole(DataIn& data)
{
    data.inputRecords.resize(40);

    HANDLE inputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD events = 0;
    DWORD unread = 0;

    DWORD fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
    //fdwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    BOOL bMode = SetConsoleMode(inputHandle, fdwMode);
    if(!bMode)
    {
        std::runtime_error("error with mode");
    }

    Sleep(20);
    BOOL statusUnread = TRUE;
    statusUnread = GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(inputHandle, &unread);
    if(!statusUnread)
        throw std::runtime_error("GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents failed.");

    data.inputRecords.resize(unread);

    BOOL statusRead = TRUE;
    statusRead = ReadConsoleInput(inputHandle, &data.inputRecords[0], unread, &events);
    if(!statusRead)
        throw std::runtime_error("ReadConsoleInput failed.");

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &data.consoleScreenBufferInfo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing the console mode just before you read cannot work, that's too late.  You have to change it in you main() function.  That blows the option to do this for a console that you don't own.  Fundamental problem is that you have *two* processes trying to read from the console.  Your code would just make the second process fail randomly.  No simple solution, you have to re-think this.

Comment: .... why are you trying to read input from the local console anyway?  I'm not sure I understand your scenario.

Comment: I need it for emulation console input and output. For example I can work with far.exe, using my program (in future obviously). It must work how local console, but execute command on another computer. But I don't now others way to do this and my tutor show me only this way.

Comment: If this program is running on the local computer, taking input from the user and (eventually) passing that input to a remote computer to be run, why are you launching a copy of `cmd.exe` ?  What is the `cmd.exe` process meant to be doing?

Comment: Yes, on a client side cmd.exe is unnecessary, but on a server side  I need excute my command: "dir", "chcp", "cd" or other. For this purpose, I create process "cmd.exe" and pass command in this process. After i just read all output and send it on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. I just created unnecessary process on a client computer. It's very stupid, but in this way I just tried to start process in new window.